# Setting Panorama Background for user control in Panorama page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, panorama-control

How set the Panorama page Background for User control which is inside the PanoramaItem ?

I had put one user control in Panorama Item. I expect that the same panoroma background is applied to user control, but its not, there is a difference..? how to set the normal Panorama Back ground to the user control which is bound to the panorama item.

```
<controls:Panorama Grid.Row="1">

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Path= Localizedresources.RecentPanoramaItemHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}">
                <views:RecentFileView DataContext="{Binding RecentFileViewModel}" />
            </controls:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item two-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Path= Localizedresources.FileserversPanoramaItemHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}">
                <views:DashboardView DataContext="{Binding DashboardViewModel}"  />
            </controls:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item three-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Path= Localizedresources.MenuPanoramaItemHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item four-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Path= Localizedresources.TheftguardPanoramaItemHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedResources}}">
                <Grid/>
           </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>
```

While I am running the application I can see the difference in Back ground of user control. I need the same feel as Panorama not the user control. for that I need the back ground of user control is same as Panorama. - while applying light theam to phone.

I need a transparent background of user control.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you're asking and provide details/examples of what you've tried. Are you saying that you have a UserControl inside a PanoramaItem and when that control is tapped (clicked) it should change the background image for the containing Panorama?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? Are you trying to set the background image for the Panorama for the first time, trying to change the background image for the Panorama based on the selected PanoramaItem, trying to set a background image for a UserControl in a PanoramaItem, or something else completely?

Comment: no its not like that.. I had put one user control in Panorama Item. I expect that the same panoroma background is applied to user control, but its not, there is difference..? how to set the normal Panorama Back ground to the user control which is bound to the panorama item.

Comment: If you set a Background for the Panorama, then that background applies to the whole control which includes all of it's PanoramaItems. If you add a UserControl to a PanoramaItem, then that control is rendered on top of the background for the Panorama. If you're not seeing the background image behing the UserControl, then you probably have a Background color defined on the root element of the UserControl. Still not entirely sure what your actual problem is, though.

Comment: The question is getting clearer now :) Does your problem exist for all items, or just one in particular? Can you show us the XAML for one of the UserControls that is not transparent, please?

Comment: @dinesh if your question is really "How do I set the background of a userControl to transparent?" can you edit the title and body of your question accordingly. What is the userconrol your using and having a problem setting the background for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that one (or more) of your UserControls has a Background value set on the root element. The default UserControl that gets added in Visual Studio has the Background property on the root Grid (named LayoutRoot) set: `Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"`, which is not transparent. If you simply remove the Background property, the UserControl will become transparent: `<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">`.